# $(this) inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize in advance if the title doesn't really describe my problem. I'm still new to javascript/jquery, and this is how I understand the problem...

I'm using a button to call up a function that appends an element to my webpage.

```
<button id="bartspbyu" class="btn btn-xs btn-success add-alert" onClick="this.disabled = 'disabled';">Add</button>
```

As you can see, when it's clicked, it disables itself.  It also uses a script to change the text from "Add" to "Added":

```
$('.add-alert').on('click', function() { 
  $('#added-alert').fadeIn('slow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#added-alert').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 2000);
  $(this).text('Added');
});
```

The user has the option to then delete the element they added. When they delete the element, the button becomes enabled again, using the following script:

```
//Reactive Add Button
   $(document).on("click", ".drartspbyu", function (){
   $("#bartspbyu").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

This works just fine, however I'm trying to get it to change the text in the button back to "Add".  I did the following:

```
//Reactive Add Button
$(document).on("click", ".drartspbyu", function (){
    $("#bartspbyu").removeAttr("disabled", function (){
      $(this).text('Add');
    });
});
```

It's enabling the button again, but it's not editing the text.  I'm not sure if I've set up `$(this)` incorrectly or if the entire thing is wrong.

I realize that I could do something like `$("#bartspbyu").text('Add');`, but the reason I'm using `$(this)` is because there are hundreds of these add buttons and I don't want to have to spend hours editing each individual ID (#bartspbyu is just one of over 400).  If I can find a way to get it to read #bartspbyu from the first instance that it's mentioned, that would save me hours of work since I would only have to do a Find + Replace and add this extra line of code to everything.

Thanks in advance for the help! Again, I'm still new at this, so I realize I'm probably missing something super obvious.

Comment: Two things. One - `removeAttr` has no callback (http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/). Just call the `.text()` on the next line (or chain the calls). Second, use `.prop()` to change the disabled state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeAttr()` does not have a callback function (http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/). You should just append to the text() since you want to apply it to the same element.

```
$("#bartspbyu").removeAttr("disabled").text("Add");
```

jQuery allows you to 'method-chain' functions. the `$("")` constructor constructs an object to which you can consequently apply multiple things, like removing an attribute and then changing the text. It works as if you typed:

```
 $("#bartspbyu").removeAttr("disabled")
 $("#bartspbyu").text("Add")
```

The advantage being that you don't actually need to repeat yourself. Also, because `removeAttr()` does not have a callback function (it only takes the name of the attribute as a parameter), it will not execute the anonymous function you passed it as it is not intended to do so.

Comment: I just know it as "chaining" - never thought where it actually came from... ["daisy chaining"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_chain_(electrical_engineering)). Thanks @somethinghere

Comment: @FelixKing indeed, I just called it daisy-chaining since it reminds me of the hardware sense of daisy-chaining (like thunderbolt daisy-chains) but I hadn't actually looked up the word! Thanks (:

Comment: @FelixKling - true true... Pretty much the same concept - wouldn't be surprised if [m]chain was  so called because it resembled [d]chain so much.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the second argument of removeAttr is a callback. Instead, just take advantage of chaining

```
$("#bartspbyu").removeAttr("disabled").text('Add');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest getting rid of the inline javascript and just adding the disabling code to that first block of jquery you have.

Comment: Its not really the question, but it is better practise and since he's already implemented an `.click()`, it would be stupid not to (:

Comment: I'll be sure to do that. Thanks for the tip!